# Zurb Foundation Reveal Disable Animation

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to disable Foundation's [Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) animation, but it's still animating.

Here's my fiddle and code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanburnett/pSQjj/

```
<script>
  $('#videoModal').reveal({  
       animation: 'none' //fade, fadeAndPop, none
  });
</script>

<a href="#" data-reveal-id="videoModal" class="radius button">Example Modal w/Video&hellip;</a>
<div id="videoModal" class="reveal-modal large">
  <h2>This modal has video</h2>
  <div class="flex-video">
    <iframe width="800" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IkOQw96cfyE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your JavaScript call to the following:

```
$(document).foundation('reveal', {animation: 'none'});
```

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pSQjj/1/

At least in this jsFiddle, it appears there may be a bug with closing the modal window with animation set to **none**, whereas it closes correctly if you change the configuration to **fade** or **fadeAndPop**. Let me know if you see the same bug in your app and I'll report it to the guys and gals at Zurb.

Comment: I'm seeing the same bug with `{animation: 'none'}`. However, `{animation: 'fade'}` and `{animation: 'fadeAndPop'}` do work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Can confirm, it does not close with animation: 'none'. In fact, this also stops the top-bar dropdowns from working.

Comment: As a hacky workaround you can do `$(document).foundation('reveal', {animation_speed: 1});`. This way it animates and closes correctly (and 1ms virtually instant).

Answer (score 1):

Change your JavaScript call to the following:

```
$(document).foundation('reveal', {animation: false});
```

The problem, is that if you turn the animation off, the modal does not animate to where you are on the page (if you have scrolled down the page) - so do take note of this.

Comment: As a hacky workaround you can do `$(document).foundation('reveal', {animation_speed: 1});`. This way it animates to the correct place on the page (and 1ms virtually instant).